# HttpWebRequest on WindowsPhone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I try to load data from web server using HttpWebRequest in Windows Phone 7 project.

I success to get data once. But when I try to call the same method to load the 2nd time, I got exception and I got this msg: "This is the next statement to execute when this thread return s from the current function."

I'm using HttpWebRequest async call from a standalone class and attached a OnCompleted event within Dispatcher to update the Windows Phone 7's UI.

```
enter code here
    private void RequestStreamCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResut)
    {
        HttpWebRequest hwr = asyncResut.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        if (hwr != null)
        {
            Stream stream = hwr.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResut);//error on this row, InvalidOperationExceptioni

            byte[] writeByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_postData);
            stream.Write(writeByte, 0, writeByte.Length);
            stream.Close();

            allDone.Set();
        }
    }
```

Should I only force to trigger the update call once every time user click on the button?
I try the add a "isLoading" flag to my code before sending calling BeginGetRequestStream(), but it's not work, I still got the exception in the Callback function.

Comment: *What* exception did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be calling `HttpWebRequest.EndRequestStream` twice on the same `IAsyncResult`:

```
InvalidOperationException - This method was called previously using asyncResult.
```

You may want to call `allDone.set` after reading and closing the response stream (instead of after writing the request stream).

See if your callback sequence matches the example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7de1x8cb.aspx

Comment: I see. Maybe I combined http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7de1x8cb.aspx sample in one class. -_-#